# Populate fields on tab using another tabs model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I want to know if it's possible to populate a tab using a separate tabs model?

I have two tabs with two separate models. Tab 2 has fields that need the info from Tab 1. Is this possible?

Tab examples:

```
tabstrip.Add().Text("Pre-screening")
         .Selected(true)
         .Enabled(true)
         .Content(Html.Partial("~/Views/EyeTestReport/_Prescreening.cshtml", new Website.Models.EyeTestReport.PreScreeningViewModel(Model.VisitID)).ToHtmlString());

tabstrip.Add().Text("Screening")
        .Enabled(true)
        .Content(Html.Partial("~/Views/EyeTestReport/_Screening.cshtml", new Website.Models.EyeTestReport.ScreeningViewModel(Model.VisitID)).ToHtmlString());
```

Field that is populated in tab 1 with the model:

```
<div style="margin-right:10px; padding-top:10px;" class="form-field">
     @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.VAL).Format("{0:n2}").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textboxC reset", id = "LeftVA" })
</div>
```

The field that needs to be populated by in tab 2:

```
<div style="margin-right:10px; padding-top:10px;" class="form-field">
     @(Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("LeftVA").Value("").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textboxC ", @readonly = "readonly" }))
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can get the numeric text value by using `var leftVA = $("#Tab1 > LeftVA").data("kendoNumericTextBox").value()` and then set it using `$("#Tab2 > LeftVA").data("kendoTextBox").value(leftVA)`. However I'm still not sure if this should be performed server-side or client-side.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto your method would also work but I have just decided to take an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to simply nest the first tabs view model into the second and then call it explicitly like this:

```
public class ScreeningViewModel
{
    public AutoRefracViewModel AutoRefractionDataModel { get; set; }
    public PupillaryDistanceViewModel PupillaryDistanceDataModel { get; set; }
    public IopViewModel IOPDataModel { get; set; }
    public HabitualRxViewModel HabitualRxViewModel { get; set; }
    public PreScreeningViewModel PreScreeningViewModel { get; set; }
    public long VisitID { get; set; }

    public ScreeningViewModel(long ID)
    {
        PreScreeningViewModel = new PreScreeningViewModel(ID); //first tab model

        AutoRefractionDataModel = new AutoRefracViewModel(ID);
        PupillaryDistanceDataModel = new PupillaryDistanceViewModel(ID);
        IOPDataModel = new IopViewModel(ID);
        HabitualRxViewModel = new HabitualRxViewModel(ID);
    }
}
```

Then call it like this on the view:

```
<div style="margin-right:10px; padding-top:10px;" class="form-field">
     @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.PreScreeningViewModel.VAL).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-textboxC ", @readonly = "readonly" }))
</div>
```